# Cannot delete record from mysql with this statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issue getting the record to delete. when i click the delete it goes through the motion no errors show up, but the record is still there. I am not sure what the issue is.

index.php

```
    //connect to database with PDO 
  $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_here;charset=utf8mb4', 'username_here','password_here');

<div class="container">
        <h2 class="panel panel-primary show_hide_e">E</h2>
        <!--Create a query to find all records starting with a and loop through them and show them bellow-->
        <?php $sql = "SELECT id, title, type, price, image, description, date FROM collection where title RLIKE '^[E]' ORDER BY type || title asc";
        $stmt->execute();

        ?><?php //start of the while loop ?>
        <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
     { 
        $image_id   = $row['image'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<h4 class='slidingDiv_e'>". 
                '<img src="https://localhost/assets/images/'.$image_id.'" width="84" height="104" />'.
                "<br>".
                $row["type"].

                " - Title:". $row["title"]. 

                " / ".

                $row["description"]. 

                " / Price: ". $row["price"].

                " / Date: ".  $row["date"].

                "<br>".
                "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='https://localhost/update.php?id=$id'>Update</a>". 
                ' '. 
                "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='https://localhost/delete.php?id=$id'>Delete</a>".
                '<hr>'.
            "</h4>";   
     }

?>
</div>
```

delete.php

```
//connect to database with PDO 
  $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_here;charset=utf8mb4', 'username_here','password_here');

//delete from database
$stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM collection WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Where do you set `$id` in `delete.php`?

Comment: That should be `$_GET['id']`

Comment: What are you expecting `ORDER BY type || title asc` to do? It probably should be `ORDER BY type, title`.

Comment: that part is working I have it in order by type and then by title then shows first title with asc  The question was about the delete portion of it.

Comment: `||` is logical OR. It won't do what you want in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It is working fine i use the two pipes as an or  I guess i can change it to the way you explain but works ether way

Comment: I changed it to ORDER BY type asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM collection WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id",$_GET['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

try this

Comment: thank you I just realized i missed the $_GET  or could have done $id = _Get['id']; above it. I never defined $id.